# Complexity of f(n) in Big O notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

```
for (i=1;i<n;i++)
{ 
    i=i*2;    
}
```

Can someone please explain what is the complexity of the above one?

For each iteration the of I is changing differently like `I*2+2`.

Comment: so are you dividing by 2 or multiplying by 2?

Comment: `i\<n` looks strange to me - what does that mean?

Comment: Those are partially my fault. I edited the code to reformat the code, those backslashes were necessary to avoid some of the symbols to be interpreted as markdown, and I didn't catch that. I've edited them back out.

Comment: This would seem to be `O(log n)` to me.

Comment: 0(log n) the addition of 2 is neglected in big numbers in comparison  to multiplication so it becomes as ```for (i=1;i<n;i*=2)
{ 
    
}```

Comment: Thank you all. 'addition of 2 is neglected in big numbers' - Sounds meaningful.